# Find length of arbitrary vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm given:
$$\|x\| = 5$$
$$\|y\| = 7$$
$$x \cdot y = -1$$

And I'm supposed to find:
$$\|x + y\| =  ?$$
$$\|x + 2y\| =  ?$$

Comment: Oops went ahead and fixed the typo, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$(x+y)\cdot (a+b)=x\cdot a + x\cdot b + y\cdot a + y\cdot b$$ where $\cdot$ denotes the usual dot product in $R^n$ and $x, y, a, b\in R^n$

To find $||x+y||$, use the above property to get $$||x+y|| =\sqrt {\langle x+y,x+y\rangle} =\sqrt {x\cdot x+x\cdot y+y\cdot x+y\cdot y}$$

You are given that $x\cdot y=-1$ and you are given $x\cdot x$ and $y\cdot y$. Now just substitute in all of the values and you have your answer. $$||x+y||=\sqrt {5-1+7-1}= \sqrt {10}$$

You can find the answer to the second part by a similar method.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also derive this using the converse of the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) which is a trivial argument that gives
$$\|x+y\|^2=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle =\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\langle x,y\rangle$$
and in general
$$\|ax+by\|^2=a^2\|x\|^2+b^2\|y\|^2+2ab\langle x,y\rangle$$

Comment: Does the less-than and greater-than signs in 2ab⟨x,y⟩ mean the inner product? And in our case, the dot product?

Comment: Indeed. It’s a convenient notation used in analysis.